# Сериализация объекта

Tags: php

Добрый день! Читаю книгу по php программированию. В главе ООП программирования наткнулся на любопытную вещь, как сериализация и десериализация объекта. Ну с методами ***__sleep()*** и ***__wakeup()*** вроде ясно, но только непонятно для чего это все нужно? Поясните смысл сериализации? Когда она применяется?

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сериализация

Comment: Равнодушный, за статью спасибо. Википедия, похоже ответила на мои вопросы... Не минусуйте меня за незнание...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гугл вроде не упал и [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.serialization.php) внорме работает, там предельно ясно все написано!

Comment: ну это понятно, что делает сериализация, функция serialize() возвращает строковое представление любого значения и обратная ей функция. Только зачем это нужно? Вот в чем вопрос. Зачем объекты загонять в строковые значения и обратно превращать из строк в объекты? На эти вопросы я ответов не получил ни в книги, ни в интернете.